# Wordpress Page titles - PHP If else

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to alter my page titles inside my header.php document and need a bit more control over them.

Currently I have an if statement that refers to another bit of PHP that said IF the page is a show page, then display the show name before the title, else do not show anything - meaning it defaults back to the main title code. Heres that code and it works perfectly:

```
<?php
  if (is_page_template( 'page-show.php' ) ) {
      echo "$show_name -";
  } else {
      echo '';
  }
  ?>

  <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?> Leicester
```

So, to gain more control over the statement, I would like it to say: IF the page is a show page then display the show name and the normal code for the title, ELSE display just the title code (which I can make different from the show code). I have tried the following, but it doesn;t seem to work - Perhaps I can't include PHP inside echo? Im not sure where the problem is...

```
<?php
      if (is_page_template( 'page-show.php' ) ) {
          echo "$show_name - <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?> Leicester";
      } else {
          echo '<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?> Leicester';
      }
      ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, you can't include the code like that, since you're already in a php block. Just concatenate.

Comment: The proper way would be to use `wp_title` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already in a PHP block, so you don't need the PHP tags again:

```
<?php
  if (is_page_template( 'page-show.php' ) ) {
      echo "$show_name - " . wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ) . " Leicester";
  } else {
      echo wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ) . ' Leicester';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Please check the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) `wp_title` will echo the title if argument 2 is true

Comment: Ah, I shall change it, thanks. I don't work with WP functions often.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more please @andrew @aynber? Why using true is incorrect?

Comment: True will output in place, and returns NULL. False returns the string. So with true, you would just use `wp_title( '|', true, 'right' )` without the echo. If you want to use the echo, then you must use `false`.

Comment: because internally the `wp_title` function will echo the title when argument 2 is true, however when false it will return it allowing you to pass it to `echo` and concatenate it

Answer (score 2):

No you can't include "< ?php" inside an echo like that. Stuff inside single quotes isn't re-evaluated by php.

The function wp_title() [returns a string](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) so you could do:

```
echo wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ) . ' Leicester';
```

Comment: Please check the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) `wp_title` will echo the title if argument 2 is true

Comment: Noted and corrected. I linked to the doc but obviously didn't read it closely enough.